# Upvote/downvote arrow colors can't be easily differentiated when color blind

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I discovered this while trying to upvote an answer on the main website I upvoted a few months ago. I Kept getting the message "you already upvoted this answer...".

It seemed strange to me, because I know that if I upvote something the arrow should have a different color, so I tried again.

After 3-4 clicks I remembered I'm color blind. So that must be it.

***Any chance the "selected" state of an up/down vote arrow can be changed?***

Any other color blind people in here experiencing the same?

[image]

Comment: Based on the [color blind simulation](https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/), red-blind and green-blind really can't see the difference while monochromacy is slightly better, but still hard to distinguish.

Comment: We'll be working on accessibility over the next few months, so it's good to know about additional concerns we might not have thought of like this. We're trying to move away from relying solely on color for indicators and this is one I'm not sure we'd thought about. Thanks!

Comment: @Catija Yes, giving the "selected" arrow a slightly darker (inner) border would certainly go a long way without disturbing overall layout too much.

Comment: Does this meta-post count as status-completed?

Comment: @Catija It *used* to be that clicked voting arrows would show up physically bigger than non-clicked ones; is it possible to reimplement that?

Comment: I can confirm that it is much better now. Thank you for the effort. I really appreciate it and probably the other colorblind users also.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like Lisa has updated this color for you! YAY! I hope that the darker shade makes it easier to distinguish - and based on the comments, it sounds like it is.

Accessibility is important to us so please let us know if you have any other situations like this that are caused by color choices. You can do that by asking a question on meta just like this one!

Thanks for speaking up!

Comment: Thank Lisa for me for the fix. yes, the dark shade makes it way better.